# how to go from emacs to xdvi

Tags: emacs, search, xdvi

I can go from `xdvi` to emacs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click but I do not know how to go from emacs to `xdvi`.  I tried to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the emacs window but it did not work.

Comment: For me `C-c C-v` does it.

Comment: Thank you - when I do C-c C-v it opens the corresponding pdf file, not the dvi.

Comment: Have you selected `xdvi` as the default viewer?

Comment: No - how shall I do that?

Comment: Something like `(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-dvi "xdvi")))`, but I'm not too sure. Please consult the official documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-Viewers.html

Comment: Thank you - I think I am getting closer.  I tried the setq suggested but it did not work.  I need to read carefully the manual.  Unfortunately, the manual lacks examples - this would make life much easier.  Thank you again!

Comment: AUCTeX is probably making a pdf file from your source and not a dvi.  Open your .tex file, and hit `C-h v TeX-PDF-mode RET`.  If the variable is set to `t`, AUCTeX creates a pdf file.  Use the command `TeX-PDF-mode` with `M-x TeX-PDF-mode RET` or hit `C-c C-t C-p` to disable the creation of pdf's and try `C-c C-a` again.  Here is the relevant part in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Processor-Options).

Comment: Thank you - I used M-x TeX-PDF-mode RET and changed to from pdf to xdvi.  The change is valid only for the open emacs window.  If I open another emacs window, it creates pdf files.  What command should I add .emacs to make xdvi the default option?

Comment: **Customize** the variable `TeX-PDF-mode` and toggle it to `nil`, i.e., to `M-x customize-variable RET TeX-PDF-mode RET` and the hit `Toggle` and `Apply and Save`.  Then restart Emacs and see if that works out for you.  Also read the doc strings carefully.